# DCGAN TUTORIAL wont train

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

So I am following this tutorial, but for a different dataset of mine. The only difference is that my dataset is of 3d images with 3 channels. But other than that, the generator is the same stracture  ConvTranspose3d -> BatchNorm3d -> ReLU
Discriminator Conv3d->  BatchNorm3d  -> LeakyReLU

and i took the training process as is, copy pasted it as is, just changed the input noise size.

The thing is that my model wont train.

The metrics I get are almost constant

[16/100][0/56]  Loss_D: 0.0000  Loss_G: 15.7471 D(x): 1.0000    D(G(z)): 0.0000 / 0.0000

with Loss_G playing from 10 to 50 , but loss d, D(x) and D(G(z)) change very little for one iteration and then go back to these values.
what am I doing wrong? I have left it to train for over two hours but still no change. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried verifying that the tutorial code works with the tutorial dataset? It could be that either your dataset is bad in some way or you didn't hook it up properly.